# How do I implement atof (ascii to float) method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, atoi, atof

I am trying to make an RPN calculator.  I have to implement my own .to_i and .to_f method.  I cannot use send, eval, Float(str) or String(str) method.  The assignment is done, but I still want to know how to implement it.

The input: atof("255.25")  as string type 
Output: 255.55   as float type

Here is my code for atoi

> ASCII_NUM_START = 48    # start of ascii code for 0
>
> def ascii_to_i(int_as_str)
>
> > array_ascii = int_as_str.bytes 
> > converted_arr = array_ascii.map {|ascii| ascii - ASCII_NUM_START } 
> > converted_arr.inject { |sum, n| sum * 10 + n  } 
> > end
>
> def ascii_to_f(float_as_str) 
> ??? 
> end

Comment: I would assume `ASCII_NUM_START = '0'.ord` (48)? Also that you mean "Output: 255.25" from your example?

Comment: hi @akh88 did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working doing the following (and utilizing your `ascii_to_i` function).

```
ASCII_NUM_START = 48 # start of ascii code for 0 


def ascii_to_i(int_as_str) 

  array_ascii = int_as_str.bytes 
  converted_arr = array_ascii.map {|ascii| ascii - ASCII_NUM_START } 
  converted_arr.inject { |sum, n| sum * 10 + n } 
end 

def ascii_to_f(float_as_str) 
  int_split = float_as_str.split(".")
  results = []
  int_split.each { |val| results << ascii_to_i(val) }
  results[0] + (results[1] / (10.0 ** int_split.last.length))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have made a reasonable effort at `ascii_to_i`.

The code for `ascii_to_f` can be similar, and in addition you will need to divide the result by the number of decimal places that you have processed.

Probably the easiest adaptation is:

- find the position of the `.` character (ASCII code 46) in the `String`, save that as a variable
- remove the `.` character (ASCII code 46) from your array of bytes
- calculate the Integer value from the array of bytes as before
- divide by `10.0` (must be a `Float`) to the power of (the length of the remaining array *minus* the position you found the `.` in).

I am not giving code, because it is an assignment. See if you can figure out the correct syntax, looking at documentation for the `Array` class for finding the position of a specific value, for deleting a specific value, and for getting length of the array.

Comment: thank you, this helps.  I didn't turn it in time for the assignment, but I wanted to learn how to do it.  I think the "." split is helpful.  I'll try your pseudocode out!